# Seg fault error for large two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, vector, malloc

I am trying to create a two dimensional array (154272 X 154272) in my program. But I am getting the segmentation fault error for `n > 40000`. I used both malloc and vector. I am wondering how can I handle this large `n`values.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 154272;
    //int n = 50000;
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
         arr[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i <  n; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
         arr[i][j] = 0;  

   for(int p=0; p<n; p++) 
     free(arr[p]);

   // I tried the following also 
   //std::vector< std::vector<int> > arr (n, std::vector< int >(n)); 
   return 0;
}
```

PS: I found some questions similar to this, but they don't talk about this large values of `n`

Comment: You are trying to allocate more than 95 GB of RAM, do you have that much installed? When allocating huge amounts of memory, check whether `malloc` returns `NULL` or just use the vector.

Comment: I am running on a cluster machine but I am not sure if I can allocate 95 GB of RAM. The use f vector does not help either. I will check if `malloc` returns `NULL`

Comment: Well the `vector` won't give you more RAM, it just automates the error handling (to some degree). If most of your entries will be zero, check out Sparse Matrices.

Comment: It is not a sparse matrix. But some elements are not used by the program at all. So I can easily make it a sparse matrix. That could fix the problem.